# C++ Visual Studio Express 2013 SDL_Init_SubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVENTS) fails

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, sdl, game-engine

I am trying to make a basic game engine, and I want the controller to be run by SDL, if it can. My end goal is to abstract out all the SDL specific code into an Controller class, but I am just trying to get it to work for now. Here is what I have got:

```
//User defined Includes
#include <Atom.h>
#include <Timer.h>
#include <Renderer.h>
#include <OGLRenderingWindow.h>

//temp includes for now
#include <Box.h>
#include <Point.hpp>
#include <Color.hpp>

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR     cmdLine,
               S32       cmdShow) 
{
//Window settings, will be abstrated out to a config file later
const S32 windowHeight          = 1072;
const S32 windowWidth           = 768;
const S32 windowBPP             = 32;
const bool windowFullScreen     = false;

//Start up OGL Window
OGLRenderingWindow programWindow(hInstance);

if(!programWindow.Init(windowHeight, windowWidth, windowBPP, windowFullScreen)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to create the OpenGL Window", "An Error occured", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    programWindow.ShutDown();
    return 1;
}

//Start Timer
Timer* timer = Timer::Instance();

Renderer* renderer = Renderer::Instance();

if(SDL_Init(0)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to initialize SDL", "An Error occured", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    programWindow.ShutDown();
    return 1;
}

if(!SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVENTS)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to initialize SDL_EVENTS", "An Error occured", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    programWindow.ShutDown();
    return 1;
}

Point<> pos(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Color<> col(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Box redbox(25.0f, 25.0f, pos, col);

pos = new Point<>(80.0f, 80.0f, 0.0f);
col = new Color<>(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

Box greenbox(25.0f, 25.0f, pos, col);

pos = new Point<>(-80.0f, 80.0f, 0.0f);
col = new Color<>(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Box bluebox(25.0f, 25.0f, pos, col);

//Main Loop Beings
while(programWindow.isRunning()) {
    //Proecess windows events
    programWindow.ProcessEvents();

    //Update the Timer
    timer->Update();

    //Test cell render
    redbox.v_Update();
    redbox.v_Render();
    greenbox.v_Render();
    bluebox.v_Render();
    //WorldManager Update

    //WorldManager Render

    //Force Render at the end of the frame
    renderer->Render();

    programWindow.Swap();
}
programWindow.ShutDown();

//redbox.v_ShutDown();
//greenbox.v_ShutDown();
//bluebox.v_ShutDown();
delete timer;
delete renderer;


return 0;
```

}

Here is the Update for the box that is being called (redbox.v_Update();)

```
void Box::v_Update(void) {

//_keyCode = _controller->UpdateInput();

SDL_Event event;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type){
        case SDL_KEYDOWN: {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_UP:
                  _velosity = Vector<F32>(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                  break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                  _velosity = Vector<F32>(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
                  break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                case 3:
                  _velosity = Vector<F32>(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                  break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                  _velosity = Vector<F32>(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
            }
        }
    }
}

F32 delta = _timer->DeltaTime() * _speed;
_position += Point<>( (_velosity.x * delta), (_velosity.y * delta), (_velosity.z * delta) );
_cell.SetPosition(_position);
}
```

I have added an error message box if SDL fails to initialize the events sub system, and as of now, it is. I am linked to SDL2.lib in my linker, and the SLD_Init(0); does not error out. I have also tried it as SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS), and it fails.

Atom.h has some typedefs that I like to use. Here it is specifically:

```
#ifndef ATOM_H
#define ATOM_H

//Includes. These will be the files that everything will need to have access to
//User defined Includes
#include <KillerMath.h>
//Sytem and library includes
#include <windows.h>

//Signed Typedefs
typedef signed __int8   S8;
typedef signed __int16  S16;
typedef signed __int32  S32;
typedef signed __int64  S64;

//Unsigned Typedefs
typedef unsigned __int8  U8;
typedef unsigned __int16 U16;
typedef unsigned __int32 U32;
typedef unsigned __int64 U64;

//Floating types
typedef float  F32;
typedef double F64;

#endif
```

So, here are my basic questions:

1. Is this the right way to handle a controller with SDL? The point is to make the controller class a component that could be added and removed from a box at runtime, based on a map of components. I want to have it this way so that I can control which object the user is in control of.
2. All of the graphics are handled by opengl, and they work fine. If I hard code the value for the key event, and force the Velocity vector to update, it moves the box without issues, so I know that part of the system is working. It appears that it is just SDL that is the issue, and it appears to be failing to Init. Can you spot anything I am doing wrong to Init SDL?

Comment: Have you checked SDL_GetError?

Comment: As I understand it on most/all platforms SDL needs a native window handle to insert itself into the event loop to hoover up events.  The usual procedure is to let SDL create that window itself via `SDL_CreateWindow()`.  Maybe try `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` and then [`SDL_CreateWindowFrom()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowFrom) with `OGLRenderingWindow`'s `HWND`?

Answer (score 0):

@Rollen you are correct, the issue was that SDL did not have a handle to the window. I tried to pass the hwnd that I am generating into SDL to get the controller/keyboard input to work, but I have not been able to get it right (most likely due to me not fully understanding SDL). In the future, I will likely make a project only use SDL so I can get a better handle on how it works. For now, DirectInput works like a champ, and I got it up and running in a very short amount of time. Thanks for the input.